# Simple Javascript Regex Question

Tags: javascript, regex

Google is failing me because ?= is not searchable.  What does

```
(?=[aeiouy])
```

match -- specifically ?=, I know that [aeiouy] is any of aeiouy.

Comment: Google is not always be the best place to start. If you're looking for information regarding Regular Expressions, you'd better to visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/ first.

Comment: Or you can just figure out what you can search for. eg: "javascript regex syntax" turns up some promising results. The first one has the answer to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?=` is the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) syntax, it matches anything *followed by* a vowel here.

Comment: See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 5):

It matches any place where the next character is an `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u` or `y`, but it doesn't match that character - see http://www.rubular.com/r/Tjq3ocLMVJ

Specifically, `(?=...)` is called a "lookahead" and it verifies that the following chunk is present

Answer (score 3):

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> x(?=y)
>
> Matches **x** only if x **is followed** by **y**.
>
> For example, /Jack(?=Sprat)/ matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat'. /Jack(?=Sprat|Frost)/ matches 'Jack' only if it is followed by 'Sprat' or 'Frost'. However, neither 'Sprat' nor 'Frost' is part of the match results.

So:

```
foo(?=[aeiouy])
```

Would match `fooe`, `fooi` etc. but not `foo` alone, but as already stated in the quote, the vowel in this case will not be included in the match itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is "bbbbae", then "(?=[aeiouy])" matches either the 'a' or the 'e', when applied anywhere before 'a'.

Comment: Not really. It doesn't match the character, it matches the *empty space before* the character. And it does so only *exactly* between `b` and `a` and between `a` and `e`, not just "anywhere before `a`".